# How to create List with multiple row and column In J2me?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I m using LWUIT in J2ME. I want to create list with 5 column and multiple row. How can done this.? I want to add data on list,and data is come from Network? plz help me. I attached my desire output image. Thanks in advance.

Eg

shape   | cut  | color |  clarity |   carats

round   | o   |   i   |   i1     |   1.000

abc     |  w  |    u  |    s     |    2.300

--      | --  |   -    |  -      | -----

### --        --    -       -         ----

### --

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a Table and not a List.

If you want a List you can use the new Container list (see the Grid Demo in the Scrolling portion of the LWUIT demo).

Comment: thanks friend. I have another question is in Table,how i can select the entire row.

Comment: You need to create a different question and start accepting answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow Table isn't designed for row selection, you can try and "fake" it by setting the UIID of cells in the row to a certain value based on focus events. But you need to decide if you want full row selection (list) or individual cell editing (table).